# What exactly do the sin, cos, tan buttons do on a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I understand they mean sine, cosine, tangent, but what exactly is the calculator doing when I enter an angle and press those buttons?

**Edit**: To help others better understand my question, my question is specifically how the calculator calculates the values.

Comment: Is your question about what the dine, cosine, and tangent functions are for, or is your question about how the calculator calculates the values of the functions?

Comment: It's a wise use of $\cos\left(\left[n + 1\right]\theta\right) + \cos\left(\left[n - 1\right]\theta\right) = 2\cos\left(n\theta\right)\cos\left(\theta\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear, so I will give two possible answers:

If you're asking what the functions sin, cos, and tan **are for**:

One very important property of trigonometric functions is they are uniquely determined for each angle. That's why they are so useful, we can ignore lengths and specific measurements and just say the sine of $30$ degrees is $\frac{1}{2}$

If your calculator is on the degree mode, it is computing the sine, cosine or tangent of an angle the size of the number you put in. Note that the sine of $390$ will be the same as that of $30$ since adding one full revolution doesn't change the angle.

However, if you want to know **how a calculator finds values** for the functions numerically, you might want to have a look at [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Basically, there's a way to write these functions as an infinite sum of powers of numbers, using methods of calculus. The calculator is just summing over the first few terms of this sequence to get an accurate approximation. For instance:

$$\sin(x) \approx x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040}$$

**Edit**: So really, if you press the sin, cos, or tan button and type in your number of degrees (°), the calculator will determine its approximate power of numbers. 
{Example above}: 
sin(x)≈x−x36+x5120−x75040

Comment: Thanks, your latter answer answered my question.

Comment: [This page](http://www.intmath.com/series-expansion/3-how-calculator-works.php) claims that (simpler?) calculators don't actually use the Maclaurin series. Do you know which ones do/don't?

Comment: I was not aware of this CORDIC algorithm, which seems quite cool, but computers have had hardware multipliers since the 70's, and today's calculators are certainly more powerful than most computers from 40 years ago. I'd say only real cheapos might not be using it, but any scientific calculator and certainly every software package uses taylor expansions.

Comment: Pure use of Maclaurin series is not found in computers either.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you have a good reference on methods specifically for trig functions?

Comment: I would have to search, there is a very big literature.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a very good article explaining the CORDIC algorithm:
http://www.qc.cuny.edu/Academics/Degrees/DMNS/Faculty%20Documents/Sultan1.pdf

(originally published in the College Mathematics Journal)